# Adding ActionListeners and calling methods in other classes

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I need some help, as I am quite the noob.

The program im trying to make here, used to work for my intentions, but as I tried to make my code more readable, I ran into a problem regarding `ActionListener`.

Before I made a new class to have all the methods in, I used `button.addActionListener(this);` and it worked just fine. Now that I wanted to put things in a separate class, I have absolutely no idea what to do.

So I guess my question is, how can I make `ActionListener` work in a situation like this, or am I just doing everything wrong here?

Here's the part of my code that I think is relevant(edited out most of it):

```
    //Class with frame, panels, labels, buttons, etc.

    class FemTreEnPlus {
        FemTreEnPlus() {
            //Components here!

            //Then to the part where I try to add these listeners
            cfg.addActionListener();
            Exit.addActionListener();
            New.addActionListener();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
        //Start the Program in the FemTreEnPlus Class
            new FemTreEnPlus();
        }     
    });  
}
```

That was the class with the frame, here's the other class, with the methods

```
public class FemTreEnMethods extends FemTreEnPlus implements ActionListener {

       //Perform Actions!
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){  
       if(ae.getSource() == cfgButton){
        configureSettings();
       }
       if(ae.getSource() == newButton){
        newProject();
       }     
       if(ae.getSource() == exitButton){
        exitProgram();
       }
 }

   //All methods are down here
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the tutorials' examples show the use of listeners implemented in the way you do, IMHO is more useful use anonymous inner classes to implement listeners. For instance:

```
cfgButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do the stuff related to cfgButton here
    }
};

newButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do the stuff related to newButton here
    }
};

exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do the stuff related to exitButton here
    }
};
```

This approach has these advantages:

- Listeners logic is well separated.
- You don't need those nested `if` blocks asking who is the source of the event.
- If you add a new button you don't have to modify your listener. Just add a new one.

Of course it depends on the case. If the behaviour will be the same for a set of components (for instance radio buttons or check boxes) then it makes sense have only one listener and use [EventObject.getSource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29) to work with the event's source. This approach is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072834/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-retrieving-value-of-button-group/22073541#22073541) and exemplified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790021/add-values-when-jcheckbox-clicked/21792361#21792361). Note the examples also make use of anonymous inner classes in this way:

```
ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do something here
    }
};
```

Comment: Although this answer is perfectly sufficient for this case, I would also try with actions. Here you've got a nice intro: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html  It will make your solution more flexible - you can use one action for many UI components and controll its "enabled" state in one place ;)

Comment: Thanks a ton! After messing around with a few errors here and there, I finally made it work the way you explained, inside a constructor(something I also have no idea what actually is).

Comment: @guitar_freak that's a good suggestion. I've never thought about use actions because I'm used to use anonymous action listeners but next time maybe I'll give it a try.