# I want to retrieve values from my JButton extension

Tags: java, swing, reference, jbutton, actionlistener

I have read that `ActionEvents` return the reference of the event object. I want to know how to extract a piece of information out of that reference. I'm sure the answer is out there, I just wasn't sure how to word my question to get it.

I have created a new class that extends `JButton`. I want each button I create to store an integer value for math operations.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
public class NewButton extends JButton {
    int value;
    public NewButton(String writing, int value) {
        this.setText(writing);
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I want to use an `ActionListener` to check for a click then I want to display the int `value` in the console. Here is my GUI:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class MyGui {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);

        NewButton button = new NewButton("ten", 10);
        panel.add(button);

        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == button) {
                    System.out.println(button.getValue());
                }
            }
        };

        button.addActionListener(listener);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(100,100);
    }
}
```

So this works fine for one button.

Now we get to my problem (finally). I want to make another `NewButton`,`button2` . I thought I would change my `ActionListener` section. I figured I could include one statement for both buttons, since they are of the same class.

```
        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == button1 || e.getSource() == button2) {
                    System.out.println(e.getSource().getValue());
                }
            }
        };
```

But this does not work.

My reasoning was that since I can check:

```
e.getSource() == button
```

then the reference `e.getSource()` should give me access to my `getValue()`.

Does anyone know a way to get the `value` from `e.getSource()`? My goal was to see if I could avoid making separate if statements or action listeners for each button.

Comment: `e.getSource()` returns on `Object`, you need to cast it to a `NewButton` in order to be able to access the `getValue` method

Comment: @fastsnail You are **wrong**. This is exactly the case when `==` should be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could cast your JButton to a NewButton and then call your method.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    NewButton newBtn = (NewButton) e.getSource();
    int value = newBtn.getValue();   
}
```

Having said this, myself, I'd prefer not to extend JButton but rather to extend AbstractAction. For example:

```
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class MyGui {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String[] texts = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();

      for (int i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
         int value = i + 1;
         panel.add(new JButton(new NewAction(value, texts[i])));
      }

      frame.add(panel);

      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}

class NewAction extends AbstractAction {
   private int value;

   public NewAction(int value, String name) {
      super(name);
      this.value = value;
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Value: " + value);
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 of course :) Just a suggestion for this apparently simple use case, wouldn't be better use button's  `put/getClientProperty()`? I mean to avoid subclassing.

Comment: @dic19: that's another valid answer. Why not post it so I can 1+ it?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @HovercraftFullOfEels great suggestion, if your use case is as simple as set/retrieve an arbitrary value then you can use the very same `JButton` to "hold" this value by using both [putClientProperty(key, value)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) and [getClientProperty(key)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getClientProperty-java.lang.Object-) methods inherited from `JComponent` class. Something like this:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Button 1");
button.putClientProperty("ValueKey", "Actual value");

ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {        
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
        System.out.println(button.getClientProperty("ValueKey"));
    };
}
```

In this way you don't have to extend neither `AbstractAction` nor `JButton` at all. Note this approach can be useful not only for buttons but other components as well. There is a complete example using the very same approach with check boxes in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790021/add-values-when-jcheckbox-clicked/21792361#21792361)